# Word for someone who loves bright colours

Tags: single-word-requests

How do we call a person having deep love towards bright colours (like he loves to wear very brightly-coloured clothes)?

Comment: How about "chromophile"? It doesn't seem to be in general use though.

Comment: If we're coining words then I suggest ***dayglophile***.

Comment: Hope someone doesn't suggest gay :P

Answer (score 4):

There is no single word to refer to such a person. But you could get plenty of adjectives to refer to bright clothes, so you may use them appropriately in the sentence you want. Some of the adjectives:

- **garish**
- **gaudy**
- **vibrant**
- **electric**

The first two words are depreciative, the latter ones are rather descriptive. Your sentence could be:

> He shows a preference for vibrant colours.

Answer (score 4):

*Chromatophilia* is sometimes used for love of colour generally (alongside, e.g., *melanophilia*, *xanthophilia*, *leukophilia* as love of black, yellow, white, respectively), but doesn't emphasize bright colours in particular.

*Augophilia*, by contrast, is the love of bright lights, glare, or sunlight.  So, it includes light, rather than just bright or glaring colour.

Maybe someone with sufficient Greek can suggest some coupling of the two ...

Answer (score 3):

I think this is best described as Colourful or Flamboyant?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for words other than the more scientific based roots (chromatophile etc.) then some further suggestions which tend to be male-biased would be:

- Peacock

[Cambridge dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peacock) a man is who is very proud of his appearance and gives a lot of attention to his clothes and the way he dresses.
Usually based on the flamboyant show of colours associated with a peacock

- Popinjay

[Cambridge dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/popinjay) someone, usually a man, who is too interested in and proud of their own appearance. Usually comes with more negative connotations.

Comment: Funny how drab the female peahen and the generic peafowl both seem compared with the male peacock.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about this myself. Even as a young boy I have always been fascinated by different colored lights. Not clothing or paint, but lighting, both natural and artificial. I feel both energized and relaxed by a light show. I have wired multi-colored lighting into bookshelves and entertainment centers in my living room and during holidays I always set up appropriate colored lights around the house inside and out.

Heliophile: (n.) a lover of the sun. 
Photophile: (n.) a person who loves light.

If I had to pick one, I would lean toward a Photophile because it isn't just sunlight that interests me.But if anyone else has a better name, then I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

In the crossword puzzle sense, with more latitude in thinking, my guesses would be painter, writer, photographer, romantic, decorator, arsonist, and, someone with a schizotypal personality disorder (who likes to wear mixed-up colored clothing).

Answer (score -2):

Actually i don't know if there is any word..
But as colors have different wavelength and our 3 cone cells see these  long , medium and short wavelengths .. so the people who love colors with different  wavelengts , i scientifically call them ...---

Simple naming of people who love different colours

1. People who love short wavelength colours - S conicellulaexcitanda  philic 
   (S conecells stimulation philic)
2. People who love medium wavelength colours - M conicellulaexcitanda philic ( M conecells stimulation philic )

3 . People who love long wavelength colours - L conicellulaexcitanda philic ( L conecells stimulation philic)

Comment: It is very doubtful that this is a real answer.  Always use links to provide evidence.