# Is there a single word for a person who loves colours in general?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests, colors

I’ve been searching for a bit and cannot find a word that means “someone who loves colours” or “someone who enjoys all colours” or something like that.

All I get are adjectives to describe people who likes bright colours. But I want a noun:

> a person who has a passion for colours and enjoys them; a person who can love each colour in its own way.

I don’t want a word for “lover of *dark* colours”, “lover of *bright* colours”, or “lover of a *certain* colour”, I want a word that means “lover of *all* colours; a person who can appreciate each and every colour”.

Comment: Depending on your purpose, you might have to invent colourphilia/colourphile

Comment: Nobody can help you to find a word that doesn't exist; you may have to settle for coining your own word or phrase.

Comment: You should add the [SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) (which requires a sample sentence) and perhaps the [phrase-requests tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests), too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from @[Daniel Harbour](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/22318/daniel-harbour) response to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73215/458041) question: Chromatophilia is

> **Chromatophilia** is sometimes used for love of colour generally
> (alongside, e.g., melanophilia, xanthophilia, leukophilia as love ofblack, yellow, white, respectively), but doesn't emphasize bright colours in particular.
>
> **Augophilia**, by contrast, is the love of bright lights, glare, or
> sunlight. So, it includes light, rather than just bright or glaring
> colour.

However, I can't really find anything that supports the answer. I imagine very few people would understand it and Google gives a definition related to biology, so I can't say I recommend it.

Comment: Yeah, the primary meaning of "chromatophile/philic" seems to be "staining readily with dyes" (compare "oleophilic"=of a chemical substance, has an affinity to oil, "hydrophilic"=has an affinity to water), so it's not great, but there isn't anything better.